# A question from a holy book about an article before an adjective

Tags: adjectives, definite-article

> And remember Ibrahim and Ishmael raised the foundations of the House (With this prayer):"Our Lord! Accept (this service) from us: For Thou art **the** All-Hearing, **the** All-knowing.

All-knowing is an adjective and I expect All-Hearing as well. Is "The" grammatically acceptable in mentioned verse above. I think it should be not because that lacks a noun

Comment: I'd say that "the All-Hearing" was a 'fused-head' noun phrase where the compound adjective "All-Hearing" combines the function of head with that of modifier. "The All-Hearing" is (presumably) understood as "the All-Hearing Allah".

Comment: It's pretty common in English to leave out the pronoun "one" and just use a bare adjective, in which case the definite article stays. Compare to: "He was the first [one] to arrive."  This sentence does the same and should be read to mean, "For Thou art the All-Hearing [one], the All-Knowing [one]."

Comment: Perfectly acceptable to use the definite article with a epithet - William the Conqueror, Jude the obscure, John the slightly-overweight etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty common in English to promote adjectives to nouns, and they usually take articles.  Some examples from titles:

- *The Naked And The Dead*
- *Lonely Are The Brave*
- *The Unforgiven*
- *The Magnificent Seven*
- *The British Are Coming*

Answer (score 0):

There are translations of the Holy Quran into English that include the definite article, and those that don't.

أَنتَ السَّمِيعُ الْعَلِيمُ

The arabic text includes ال (the) before each word. As in English, placing the definite article before an adjective indicates that the adjective is qualifying rather than descriptive, for example:

> The wine is red. - *descriptive*
>   I'll take **the** red wine. - *qualifying*
>   I'll take **the** red. - *qualifying, with noun omitted*

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20_ADJ_%20_END_&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20_ADJ_%20_END_%3B%2Cc0) shows that the usage of **the** + adjective at the end of a sentence is quite common.

The translations that include **the** are therefore both grammatically correct and more authentic.